# Avro - Unable to serialize payload org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type java.math.BigDecimal: 8.32

Tags: java, unit-testing, serialization, apache-kafka, avro

I'm writing unit test to one of the method which is sending event to kafka.

In avro schema I have defined filed

```
union { decimal(10, 2), null } cost
```

which is represented in Java as BigDecimal.

In the unit test I'm using DatumReader for reading if event was correctly sent to topic.

```
    private final DatumReader<Event> eventReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(Event.class);

    //reading message from topic
    final ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> eventMessage = KafkaTestUtils.getSingleRecord(
        kafkaConsumer, eventTopic, ofSeconds(10).toMillis()
    );
    final Event event = eventReader.read(
        null,
        DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(eventMessage.value(), null)
    );
```

And finally I'm receiving an error

> Unable to serialize payload
> org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum type java.math.BigDecimal: 8.32

Is anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I suggest removing Kafka from your test path to further debug the issue since you only need to test serialization, not the consumer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally adding

```
GenericData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new Conversions.DecimalConversion());
```

before calling read() method

```
final Event event = eventReader.read(
    null,
    DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(eventMessage.value(), null)
);
```

fixed the problem.